# Apache VirtualHost being ignored

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, virtualhost

I have a web app running on apache normally without any issue. The problem is that now **I'm trying to add a new domain for this same app and I can't get it to work properly**.

I've put two new ServerAlias with my new domain and subdomain but it looks like it is being ignored for some reason. When I enter the domain on my browser, I get an error 404.

Here is my "**sites-available/olddomain.com.conf**":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName olddomain.com
    ServerAlias *.olddomain.com
    ServerAlias newdomain.com
    ServerAlias *.newdomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/MakePress/MakePress/web
    <Directory /var/www/MakePress/MakePress/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On

            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also tried to just change the ServerName and the ServerAlias to the new domain like this:

```
ServerName newdomain.com
ServerAlias *.newdomain.com
```

but curiously, the *newdomain.com* keeps not working and the *olddomain.com* keeps working normally even without its entry on the .conf file. On the other hand, I've tried to remove **sites-available/olddomain.com.conf** with `a2dissite` and both domains stopped working (both started to show the "Index of /" of the application - just showing the folders and files inside the www folder - and no error 404 was shown)

After each modification I execute `service apache2 reload` and `apache2 restart`.

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! :-(

Thanks!

PS: Should it matter to identify the problem, my site is a PHP/Symfony 2.3 application.

PS2: Here is the output for `apache2ctl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   olddomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/olddomain.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Comment: Have you put the new domain name in your DNS or HOSTS file?

Comment: Have you checked under **sites-enabled/olddomain.com.conf**?

Comment: I'm sure the DNS/hosts file is fine, otherwise you wouldn't be getting a 404 from the web server, it would be a name not resolved issue.

Comment: how many other virtual hosts are you running? which one is it resolving to on the new name? Is it safe to assume it's apache's `000-default` site since it's showing the file index of `/var/www`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. Yes, I have checked **sites-enabled/olddomain.com.conf** and there is a perfect copy of **sites-available/olddomain.com.conf**

When I ran `apache2ctl -S`, the output seems to say that only `olddomain.com` is running. I will edit the question with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys,

It turned out it was a problem with the Symfony configuration.

The parameter `basehost` on my **parameters.yml** was set to **olddomain.com** so the application was not accepting my **newdomain.com**.